# Regular Expression for name should NOT contain "www." and name should NOT be numbers only in angularjs

Tags: regex, angularjs

Can you please tell me the Regular Expression for **name should NOT contain "www." and name should NOT be numbers only in angularjs** using ng-pattern. Here I want to show two different error messages like:

1. name should NOT be numbers only
2. name should NOT contain "www.

Based on the input it will show any one of those messages.

I tried like this `/^((?!www.).)*$/`, it is working for name should NOT contain "www." not for another means "name should NOT be numbers only". If I'm adding | (OR) condition it is showing both messages.

Comment: You seem to be asking for a `regex` and how to do form validation in angularjs.  Could you narrow it down some and tell us what you have tried and be clearer about what isn't working.

Comment: Yes i want to get two validations for one ng-pattern, but this ng-pattern must contain two regular expressions for 
    name should NOT be numbers only
    name should NOT contain "www.    Example: <textarea cols="50" rows="10" ng-model="titleFld" id="titleFld"  name="titleFld" ng-maxlength="300" ng-pattern="/[a-z]/">Title</textarea>   <li ng-show="myForm.bio.$error.pattern"><span>Bio should NOT contain "www." </span></li>

Comment: Yes i want to get two validations for one ng-pattern,but this ng-pattern must contain two regular expressions for "name should NOT be numbers only" and name should NOT contain "www". Example:<textarea cols="50" rows="10" ng-model="bio" id="bioFld" ame="bio"ng-pattern="/^((?!www\.).)*$/">Bio</textarea>   In this ng-pattern i want to add another regular expression for name shoud not number only and i want to display validation message also,here one ng-pattern is there but want to add two validation mesgs . <li ng-show="myForm.bio.$error.pattern"><span>Bio should NOT contain www."</span></li>

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way to show two different error messages with ngPattern. The cleanest solution would probably be custom directives for validation. You could also try using the uiValidate directive from [AngularUI](http://angular-ui.github.io/), which lets you call a custom validation function.

Untested uiValidate example:

```
<input name="name" type="text" ui-validate="{www:'validateNotWww($value)', numbers:'validateNotNumbers($value)'}"/>
<span ng-show="form.name.$error.www">Name should NOT contain "www."</span>
<span ng-show="form.name.$error.numbers">Name should NOT be numbers only.</span>
```

validateNotWww and validateNotNumbers would be functions defined on your $scope.

Comment: I got it. Thanku so much.

Comment: $scope.validateNotWww=function(value){
     alert("jesus");
     return true;
    }   I wrote this function in my js, but that alert is not at all coming, iam new to angularjs could please help on this?  In html i added like this   <textarea cols="50" rows="10" ng-model="bio" id="bioFld" name="bio" ng-pattern={{bioPatterns}}  ui-validate="{www:'validateNotWww('$value')', numbers:'validateNotNumbers($value)'}" ng-change="bioChange()">Bio</textarea>

Comment: $scope.validateNotWww=function(value){
     alert("jesus");
     return true;
    }   I wrote this function in my js, but that alert is not at all coming, iam new to angularjs could please help on this?  In html i added like this   <textarea cols="50" rows="10" ng-model="bio" id="bioFld" name="bio" ng-pattern={{bioPatterns}}  ui-validate="{www:'validateNotWww('$value')', numbers:'validateNotNumbers($value)'}" ng-change="bioChange()">Bio</textarea>,   Can you please tell me how can i create ui-validate directive with this patterns?  Hoping here from you soon, thanku, Kumari.

Comment: Can you please tell me the how to create custom directive for ui-validate by using below tag?    <input name="name" type="text" ui-validate="{www:'validateNotWww($value)', numbers:'validateNotNumbers($value)'}"/>
<span ng-show="form.name.$error.www">Name should NOT contain "www."</span>
<span ng-show="form.name.$error.numbers">Name should NOT be numbers only.</span>